# S3 pre-signed url Access Denied when created from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to generate pre-signed s3 URLs using a Lambda, however it is always returning "Access Denied".

Here is my signing code:

```js
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-2")})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    svc := s3.New(sess)

    key := strconv.FormatInt(accountID, 10) + "/"

    params := &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket:    aws.String(os.Getenv("S3_USER_BUCKET")),
        Prefix:    aws.String(key + loc[0] + "/"),
        Delimiter: aws.String("/"),
    }


    resp, err := svc.ListObjectsV2(params)


    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Create S3 service client

    if *resp.KeyCount == 0 {
        return nil, nil
    }


    for _, key := range resp.Contents {
        if *key.Size == 0 {
            continue
        }
        req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(os.Getenv("S3_USER_BUCKET")),
            Key:    aws.String(*key.Key),
        })


        urlStr, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute)
```

I have setup the following Lambda Permissions Execution role:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The role assigned to my Lambda has the following Trust Policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

And a Maximum Session time of 1 hour.

My Lambda lives inside a VPC and my S3 Bucket denies public access. The S3 Bucket has the following policy assigned to it:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3BukcetPolicyVPCAccessOnly",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyIfNotFromAllowedVPC",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::iscore-users",
                "arn:aws:s3:::iscore-users/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-{ID HERE}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to list the objects correctly from my lambda, and get a response that looks like this:

```
2023-03-10T18:49:11.275-05:00   Contents: [{

2023-03-10T18:49:11.275-05:00   ETag: "\"TAG\"",

2023-03-10T18:49:11.275-05:00   Key: "KEY",

2023-03-10T18:49:11.275-05:00   LastModified: 2023-03-10 17:23:30 +0000 UTC,

2023-03-10T18:49:11.275-05:00   Size: 3664382,

2023-03-10T18:49:11.275-05:00   StorageClass: "STANDARD"

2023-03-10T18:49:11.275-05:00   }
```

Here is an example of a URL that is generated:

```
https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/35/Scotland/Inverness/c2b8e69f-b746-4a7c-97ef-1931573c338c?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQMATP5I3KR3QUD74%2F20230310%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230310T234911Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMiJGMEQCIA6BAtAHaqXuqBVug4s%2BAwU5tGPaTbYaRUEAU4Wg8mG2AiBnQwyfLnb4ryPlKX2PLGWEUkHKtQHSaJRy77XaNHelryrxAgiB%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAAaDDAyNTgxMDY5MjY2MiIMq7OanPDNAOiHaVpoKsUCorxYhoNxj1YyF7d4pcnrur1ndrWVDAaZbkF2LWyqExG1%2F57Ocdyc74GuYgd6x%2FLGLNzkXJt6NZryvrK2xy0Zx5Gg0Jxf9mmvaC5MCPrhpkgfA92U%2F1sJ5odFwyzsbK%2F2WzvY6gy1t5hT0zTcVebu%2BZ0vMCS5BqfSQJcTKMNi%2FRqZTpsb8CRjjakkIuj27ZfJirdmzykWYK9N7b4Mgm1LCBsf643V2uUsw1mUzfkzaZeTSLXYcteHN%2FTajHGt82Bh8Vzgq6%2BuAj7Yh0%2BIBJVyqK1sIdT9UgWiQt%2F09th2ep4cwEJ8ApKB0Cbl3YejevZ9QbIBluZJnKbnu%2B26RZ9N4ZvTW0hdHnWHbQJOA%2Fz43btJGLQTvbPJl2P%2BlYbCnyKXA5X6Kh56CeW8y%2FNoGmkTM%2B7GZ%2FsHXfpHUlg6ueM6iQRprMMejzDxg6%2BgBjqfAXjiT1zTkBYbE9ntg5cgZuOmVS%2B66tNTeOXMkAbd%2BU3fSssBFZQgBN0WMwfyCMCUrs7aWw6coRntFofOHdpvwK%2FKSnmydYPbuxcH7FvJH%2FV4pwEFzMfjwgkcQQyEJCAF%2Bt3JX2xEltX5D7NO3jB8hU4yGdo9ZOpfhuWT3AUJMS0LU8hYfMCc%2BhrL%2F%2BrljKJ5NVLQEpj8gX7nJViORpOyUQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=19472da6b7b3f77bff201be08b6bf9417222395f82c565d632661f78f5344d60
```

If I make my objects public then it works, but I do not want my objects to be public.

I am accessing the generated URLs within seconds of them being created, so I do not think it is to do with Lambda Creds expiring.

I am also able to upload to the bucket using the same Lambda without issue.

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong here?

Comment: From where are you trying to access the object via the pre-signed URL? Is it from your own computer on the Internet, or from the Lambda function, or perhaps some other resource within the VPC?

Comment: You need to create an interface/gateway endpoint for the S3 bucket, so that the lambda can access from the VPC.

Comment: I don’t think this is an access issue. As mentioned in the post I am able to read items from and upload items to the bucket, via the same lambda, If this was an access issue I would expect those operations to also fail.

Comment: I am trying to access the presigned url from my own machine. My understanding of presigned urls is that once something with the correct permissions generates them they can be accessed from anywhere, by anyone.